# R Data Frame summary showing factor frequency and total percentage

Tags: r

I have an R data frame "internet" containing the following data:

```
> internet
   Time       Domain    Category File_Type
1   1.9   google.com  News_Media      html
2   2.0   google.com  News_Media       css
3   2.0   google.com  News_Media       jpg
4   2.1   google.com  News_Media       jpg
5   4.0 facebook.com      Social      html
6   4.0 facebook.com      Social       jpg
7   4.1 facebook.com      Social       css
8   5.9    bbc.co.uk  News_Media      html
9   6.0    bbc.co.uk  News_Media       css
10  6.0    bbc.co.uk  News_Media       jpg
11  6.1    bbc.co.uk  News_Media       jpg
12  6.0 facebook.com      Social      html
13  6.0 facebook.com      Social       jpg
14  6.1 facebook.com      Social       css
```

I'd like to create a summary of this data like as follows, though I am struggling to find the right way to do this.

```
Domain         Frequency   Total Percentage
bbc.co.uk      4           28.57143
facebook.com   6           42.85714
google.com     4           28.57143
```

I am able to produce a factor of Domains using:

`domains <- tapply(internet$Domain, internet$Domain, FUN=length)`

and a factor of totalPercentage using:

`totalPercentage <- (domain/nrow(internet))*100`

but I'm not quite sure how to join these into one summary.

Thank you all in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this:

```
multi.fun <- function(x) {cbind(freq = table(x), percentage = prop.table(table(x))*100)}
multi.fun(proxy$Domain)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you instal the [epicalc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epicalc/index.html) package, you can get this with [?codebook](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/epicalc/html/codebook.html).  Consider:

```
proxy <- read.table(text="Row   Time       Domain    Category File_Type
1   1.9   google.com  News_Media      html
2   2.0   google.com  News_Media       css
3   2.0   google.com  News_Media       jpg
4   2.1   google.com  News_Media       jpg
5   4.0 facebook.com      Social      html
6   4.0 facebook.com      Social       jpg
7   4.1 facebook.com      Social       css
8   5.9    bbc.co.uk  News_Media      html
9   6.0    bbc.co.uk  News_Media       css
10  6.0    bbc.co.uk  News_Media       jpg
11  6.1    bbc.co.uk  News_Media       jpg
12  6.0 facebook.com      Social      html
13  6.0 facebook.com      Social       jpg
14  6.1 facebook.com      Social       css", header=T)

library(epicalc)
codebook(proxy)
... (output skipped)
================== 
Domain    :       
             Frequency Percent
bbc.co.uk            4    28.6
facebook.com         6    42.9
google.com           4    28.6
... (output skipped)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! epicalc looks like a very useful library!

Comment: It looks like that [epicalc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epicalc/index.html) library was removed from the CRAN repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer is exactly what I was looking for.  Slight change below with formatting of percentage for readability.

```
multi.fun <- function(x) {
 cbind(freq = table(x), 
 percentage = round(prop.table(table(x))*100, 2))
}
multi.fun(proxy$Domain)
```